# How to count total character if some keyword are present in a cell?

Tags: excel

I would like to count the total number of "X" from cells only from where at least five "X"( "XXXXX") are present.I tried as follow but not able to correct it. Some where it got error.tried putting - LEN(A1:A20) in false statement it shows error.

Total Xs only from cells containing "XXXXX"

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1:A20)-LEN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("XXXXX",A1:A20)),SUBSTITUTE(A1:A20,"X",""),)))
```

Table

```
XXXXXXXX
XXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX
UUU
UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
XXXX
UUUUUUUUU
XXX
X
XX
XXX
UUUUUU
XXXXXXXXX
UUUUUXXXXX
XXXXX
XXUUU
XXXXXXX
UUUUUUUUUU
XXXX
UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
UXXXX
XXXXXX
```

Thank you in advance for ur help:)/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

multiply the boolean of the search with the Len:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A1:A24)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A24,"X","")))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH("XXXXX",A1:A24)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is close to magic - nicely done!  ...not I get to sit here and think through how it works (especially as it's not a CSE formula).

Comment: It might not require CSE but it is an array formula.  It will iterate each cell in the range and do the functions for each.  @BruceWayne

Comment: @ScottCraner - whelp I need to study up on non-CSE Array formulas. I didn't realize you could do such formulas *without* CSE.  Thanks!